# Should we pass the Library Title or Library Name inside this PnP Function " Get-PnPListItem -List"

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, pnp-powershell, library, pnp

Should we pass the Library/List Title or Library/List Name inside this PnP Function?

```
Get-PnPListItem -List"
```

Now based on my test both will work, so could the PnP fail safe to get the library title incase the library name is missing?

Thanks.

Comment: List title is the "name" of a list, I'm not sure what you mean: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee545367(v=office.15)

Comment: @CallumCrowley the name is what is inside the url , title can be changed , name can not!!

Comment: Actually, List title can be changed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee545356(v=office.15) The URL suffix or name as you refer to cannot be changed

Comment: @CallumCrowley when you create a list and you give it a name  >> this will be the list name & title

Comment: after that if you modify the list title >> its name (which is part of the url) will not be chnaged

Comment: so my question is if the `Get-PnPListItem -List"` will expect the list name or the lit title ?

Answer (score 0):

`Get-PnPListItem` command in PnP PowerShell uses `Get-PnPList` command internally.

`Get-PnPList` command works with the ID or Name or URL (Lists/MyList) of the SharePoint list.

**Examples**:

**By ID**:

```
Get-PnPList -Identity 99a00f6e-fb81-4dc7-8eac-e09c6f9132fe
```

Internally uses: `web.Lists.GetById(_id)`

**By Name**:

```
Get-PnPList -Identity Announcements
```

1. If you have created a list/library without space or special characters, display name of list (title) and name in URL will be same. So, if you use title or name, both will work.
2. If you have different display name and name in URL, use title by enclosing in double quotes like: `Get-PnPList -Identity "My Announcements List"`
3. Internally uses: `web.GetListByTitle(_title)`

**By URL**:

```
Get-PnPList -Identity Lists/Announcements
```

Internally uses: `web.GetListByUrl(_url)`

**References**:

1. [Get-PnPList](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPList.html)
2. [ListPipeBind.cs](https://github.com/pnp/powershell/blob/2acfb5c8a0dfe2bae0c1706cd8f9662f93a0f064/src/Commands/Base/PipeBinds/ListPipeBind.cs#L10)

Comment: @Gamesh Sanap you did not get my question.. now let us take the built-in Document library. it  has a title (which can be changed) of "Documents" while it name (which can not be changed and it will be part of the url) of "Shared Dcouments".. so my question is if the `Get-PnPListItem -List` will expect the list name or the list title ?

Comment: based on my test bot the listname and listtitle will work

Comment: Based on my test... `Get-PnPListItem -List "Documents` or `Get-PnPListItem -List "Shared Documents"` will both work for the same list

Comment: You didn't read the answer, both will work. The code behind to fetch the list for Get-PnPListItem and Get-PnPList is the same code and it accepts both list URL name and Title
https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPList.html#-identity

Comment: @johnGu, it will work with both as Get-PnPList works with ID, Title or URL name. `Get-PnPListItem` uses `-List` which is of type `ListPipeBind`. If you check the last reference link given in my answer, you will find that it works with ID, Title or URL name (check from line #45). First it tries to get list with `GetById`, if not found it will try to get list with  `GetListByTitle()` else using `GetListByUrl()`.

Comment: @GaneshSanap but it will also accept the name only without the relative url

Comment: @GaneshSanap a bit confusing

Comment: @johnGu this is consistent with the documentation on Get-PnPList which uses the same code: https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPList.html#-identity "The ID, name or Url (Lists/MyList) of the list"

Comment: @johnGu I think it will access the name only for document libraries as library URL is generally having name directly after site URL in format: `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/libraryName`.